# Excited state frequency for periodic systems

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-espresso, ab-initio-calculations, solid-state-physics

Is there any way to calculate the excited state frequencies of a period system using DFT?

Comment: Considering that many excited states are quasiparticles/multi-body in nature, it seems like a non-trivial calculation for many reason. What kind of excited states are you exactly looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the lowest optically allowed(singlet) transition.

Comment: @Greg might not have seen your response, because you didn't use the @ character to ping him. In the future please remember to ping people by using the @ character. Also, since it has now been more than 10 months since you asked this question, have you found an answer yet, or made any progress on this project?

Comment: @NikeDattani I didn't get any answer. CP2K can do excited state optimization. I think that interfacing cp2k with phonopy might solve this.

Comment: Why do you need to interface it with phonopy?

Comment: @NikeDattani I am trying to get excited state frequencies.

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. Shall we close this question?

Comment: @NikeDattani. Yes. We can close this question.